# Unexpected tuple with StructType - Error in pyspark when using schema to create a data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do the following:

```
subschema = T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
    T.StructField("AA", T.LongType(), True),
    T.StructField("BB", T.StringType(), True),
]), True)
s = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("B", subschema, True),
    T.StructField("A", T.StringType(), True),
])
d = [Row(
    B=None,
    A="AAA",
)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d, schema=s)
```

But I am getting an error that does not make sense to me:
`ValueError: Unexpected tuple 'A' with StructType`

If I comment either row A or row B, the error disappears, but I don't understand why this is happening. What is the problem? Is this a bug, or is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the alphabetical ordering of the fields when you create a Row using keyword arguments. Here it tries to apply the type of `B` to the field `A`.

In Spark 3, this was [removed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29748), I was able to run your code without any error.

For Spark < 3, you need to sort the fields in your schema too, `A` before `B` :

```
s = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("A", T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField("B", subschema, True)
])
```

Or simply create RDD from tuple:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(None, "AAA")])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=s)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have see that using a dictionary instead of a Row also works, so I don't need to change the order in my schema:
```d = [{"B": None, "A": "AAA"}]```